# Visual hierarchy of typography in UI in practice

Tags: gui-design, human-interface-guideline, visual-design, information

There are so many resources about this in theory, but I can't find any detailed guides or resources on how to apply the principles in an existing complex UI. The most obvious ones would be differentiation by copy size, in many UIs like in facebook and youtube that manage to pull off a good hierarchy at the micro level as well as the macro level.

What would be a good guide or process to follow?

Comment: Are you asking how to achieve visual weight in general or how to achieve visual weight in/via typography alone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some resources I'd personally recommend when it comes to the practical side on fonts in (web) UI development would be:

- [Professional Web Typograhy](https://prowebtype.com/)
- [Type Scale calculator](http://type-scale.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Rank all of the text elements in order of importance and use the classic typographic scale to assign an appropriate font size to each element.

Answer (score 0):

It's not an online guide or process, but I found Robin Williams' [Non-Designer's Design Book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0133966151) to cover this sort of thing pretty well when I was starting out. (I can't comment on the fourth edition, though... I still have the first edition!)

Answer (score 0):

Check this: [vanseodesign.com/web-design/visual-balance](http://vanseodesign.com/web-design/visual-balance) > 14 Factors that Influence Visual Weight.